# Having a problem with PrimeReact Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am still a novice in React Js and recently I have been developing using PrimeReact. The Forms and DataTables are doing well for me but I cant seem to figure out how deal with the Dropdown. My state is managed by redux and after `mapStateToProps` I and loading my data using `componentDidMount` I can `console.log` and see my data array. With a normal react select input I have been using the following code:

```
const {accounttypes} = this.props;

    console.log(accounttypes)
    let typesOptions = accounttypes.length > 0
        && accounttypes.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <option key={item.id } value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
            )
        }, this);
```

This works as an option as I can post to my backend. However I would want to use PrimeReact for all my forms and I have been struggling on how to go about it. The following has been my attempt and its giving me a headache:

```
<div className="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4">
                <Dropdown
                  value={account_type}
                  optionValue = {accounttypes.id}
            
                  optionLabel = {accounttypes.name} 
                  options={accounttypes}

                  onChange={this.onTypeChange}
                  placeholder="Select an Acco"
                  autoFocus = {true}
                  editable={true}
                />
</div>
```

`account_type` is the name of my field and my django model references the `accountytpe` model and would like to capture `account_type` whilst creating an `Account`. May someone help. And thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optionLabel` and `optionValue` should point to equivalent properties of your object. In your case I guess the correct way is this

```
                  optionValue="id"
                  optionLabel="name"
```

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos and if I may ask how do I refer to the properties for if I put id and name it says its undefined. Do I have to define the name and id in the state or there is a function that has to extract the id and name ???.

Comment: these are the properties of your object. how can id be undefined? that;'s weird

Comment: thank you so much its working like how you said I should put it. I guess when I referred to those objects there were typos. Thank you so much you made my day

Comment: again thanks and I have learnt a new trick that when answered you accept the answer.I am very grateful for what you did for me